# Glitch in latest update- galactic registry

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Has anyone else had trouble with the august update? After downloading , I lost deep core bitizen, and bitizens in galactic registry have changed appearance as well as a few in limited edition. They now look
Nothing like they are supposed to

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Currently it is hard to tell exactly what you are asking.

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly your issue is.  I know there's a problem in your question, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what it is.  Can you reword your question to focus less on, "Does anyone else have this problem?", and more on what the actual problem is, please?  Hopefully that way we can get solutions to solve the problem you're having, then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The update on august 6 went awry across 3 different IOS devices in my household.

1. Deep core bitizen changed to Lando Calrisian, cannot change appearance either.
2. Loss of clarity on level names.
3. Imperial Assignments level is glitchy in appearance.
4. All Imperial items (Sith Warrior, Interrogation droid) show as a stoplight icon

Something is definitely not right as I have verified this across an Apple ipad 3, iPad mini retina, and an iPhone 5.  Also this was directly after having to hard reset the devices because after the update the screen froze on startup.